# Kolmogorov Complexity proving there exists a constant for when if two strings are equal length

Tags: turing-machines, information-theory, kolmogorov-complexity

When talking about kolmogorov complexity, I understand that it describes true randomness of given (for now) a string $x$, if we can describe x in less than the $|x|$ then its complexity is said to be

> $C(x) \leq |x| + c$

my question lies in finding that c for a given problem.

Given this problem

> there is a constant $c$ $∈$ $\mathbb{N}$ such that, for $\forall$ x,y ∈ $\{0,1\}^+$ with $|x|=|y|$
>
> $H(x,y)$ is the hamming distance between $x$ and $y$
>
> $ C(y)$ ≤ $C(x)$ $+ 2·H(x,y)·$(1 + $ \lceil log|x|\rceil $)$ + c$

How would I go about mathematically proving there there is a constant $c$ $∈$ $\mathbb{N}$ what does finding a constant tell us

> Constant is defined as follows
>
> as in what does this given a TM M and universal TM $u$ s.t. there exists a constant $c_M$ s.t. $C_u(x) \leq C_M(x) + c_M$(From Solomonoff and turing's theorem)?

Comment: What do you mean by "optimality constant"?

Comment: I think it says that given a universal TM u  and a standard TM M that computes x we get the optimality constant to be $C_u(x) \leq C_M(x) + c_M$ . so a universal TM is always going to be optimal. I guess you could just say constant if that makes more sense

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/90242/755, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/40531/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a procedure which has two inputs, $P$ and $DIFF$. Here $P$ is a self-delimiting program, and $DIFF$ is a list of indices, stored in some self-delimiting fashion (we leave the encoding vague for now). The procedure runs $P$, flips all the indices in $DIFF$, and prints the output. Using the invariance property of Kolmogorov complexity, we immediately get that there is a program of length $|P|+|DIFF|+O(1)$ which simulates the procedure above.

Now take any two vectors $x,y$. Let $P$ be a self-delimiting program of size $C(x)$ producing $x$, and let DIFF be the list of differences, which can be encoded using $H(x,y)(1+\lceil \log |x| \rceil)$ bits (this improves on your exercise; we're using the fact that $|x|$ is known by the procedure). It follows that $C(y) \leq C(x) + H(x,y)(1+\lceil \log |x| \rceil) + O(1)$.

Comment: the procedure you talk about is the Turing machine that computes P? could you also briefly elaborate on the invariance property of kolmogorov complexity?

Comment: No, the procedure accepts P (and DIFF) as inputs.

Comment: The invariance property states that we can simulate every "computer" at an additive loss. I don't remember the official name of the property, but it's a basic feature of Kolmogorov complexity, so you probably learned it.

Comment: The basic approach is what I use in my answer. Another basic technique is dovetailing.

Comment: I understand your skeleton proof completely, just confused on small part about the self-delimiting program P. is this analogous in saying P is shortest description for the string x?

Comment: Yes, eventually we choose P this way.